# What would be the best thing to do when you post a question and then realize it's already been asked

Tags: discussion

I just asked a question and find out its a duplicate, now what should be the best thing to do, as If you delete your question, I think SE keeps a track and after a certain amount it bans you from asking questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you don't delete it, someone else likely will.

I suppose as an alternative you could flag your own post and mark it as a duplicate, but this is just adding noise to the moderators' queues.

I think your best bet is just to delete the post (or use that little box in the corner that says "search" before you post a question).

Comment: I tried searching it using the "search" box but sometimes if keywords are different then search results won't gonna show you the exact similar posts.

Comment: I usually use google: blah blah blah site:sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: Lol, Nice 1 but I wonder if there is any difference between Google and SE search as they both work same ways, they use keywords to perform searches and if keywords doesn't match it will not gonna come back with all expected results.

Comment: little notice: AFAIK deleting your question will add a nice +1 on your question ban point card, so take that in account, too.

Comment: @SPArchaeologist, how many points gets you banned from asking questions?

Comment: @rjcup3 - I don't know... I only know that everytime some vampir.. new user post on meta cryin.. asking why he can't ask questions some one points out that deleted questions that aren't 30 or more days old count for the auto-ban. If this means that deleting a question with less that 30 days age gives you a +1 or that you won't erase any bad effect of the question if you delete it before six month.... only staff knows.

Comment: Anyway, If I should place my bet - I would go for the first option: the system gives you a +1 elixir of ban if you delete a question. I also belive it could work on a % of deleted question vs the total: if it is the case, and if Jeff never forgets his towell, I declare that the magic percentage is 42.